# How to Configure SAML authentication using pingfederate using ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: model-view-controller, pingfederate

I am already having mvc application in .net along with SAML authentication with wsFederation. I need to implement ping federate for my application. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

PingFederate supports WS-Federation. [See docs here for version 8](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf84/#task_specifyingServiceUrlWsFederation.html#task_specifyingServiceUrlWsFederation) and [version 9](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf90/index.shtml#task_specifyingServiceUrlWsFederation.html#task_specifyingServiceUrlWsFederation).